# Understanding log numbers in standard terms

Tags: logarithms

How do I convert these numbers to regular terms `8.26 (1.24) log` and `9.12 (0.64) log` (source "results" section of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25760553)?

Comment: Put it at the exponent of the base of log.

Comment: @BAI - Sorry, I'm not sure what "it" is referring to.  Would you mind showing an example on one of the two? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source says:

> The mean (SD) numbers of Bifidobacterium species bacteria in feces
>   during the first 6 mo of life was lower in affected children 8.26
>   (1.24) log cells/g than in healthy children 9.12 (0.64) log cells/g;

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colony-forming_unit, it seems the base of logarithm in counting bacteria is base 10. So 8.26 (1.24) log cells/g means the average number of bacteria per gram is $10^{8.26}$ with standard deviation $10^{1.24}$.